# Yarn Project Not Working After Mac OS Ventura Installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, macos, macos-ventura

I have updated my mac's OS and when I try to run the same commands that I did prior to the update (see file, it was simply just `yarn`), I get a vomit of errors on my terminal and I get a system prompt that states: `The "make" command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?` After I click Install it takes about 20 minutes and it says installation finished, only to have the same behavior when I run the same command in my terminal.

Any one else a developer using Ventura running into weird problems running their code base?

Will be happy to share my output logs if somebody cares to help.[image: picture]

Did exactly what system prompts said, only to give me the same behavior when trying to run my code locally. It is in a feedback loop and am un sure how to approach it at this point.

Comment: the question belongs to other stack exchange forums and is not related to nodejs or reactjs , ... tags you specified. you can also ask your question in related forums

Comment: @nima it is related to the yarn package manager.

Comment: over night for some reason it worked. I think apple did a patch over night

Answer (score 0):

This question is about 5 months old at the time of me answering it, but I'm going to answer it for any future people that might land on this page.

The outlined error of "required the command line developer tools" is often related to XCode. More than likely your problems will be fixed by installing/updating the XCode Command Line Tools.